# Azure AD B2C: Remediation for risky user by using conditional access technical profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I tried to use this example (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/conditional-access/policy) to call the conditional access evalution, force an user to pass the MFA if it's needed, and then remediation. Then I configured the Conditional Access policies separatly based on User risk (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/concept-identity-protection-risks#user-linked-detections) and Sign-In risk (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/concept-identity-protection-risks#sign-in-risk). And I found that for "Sign-In risk" policy when an user passes the MFA step, the risk is marked as "Remediated". But when I use "User risk" policy, no remediation occurs, the user is still has Risk state "At risk" in the Risky users report.
The question is, is there any way to remediate a risky user with a custom B2C policy?

Answer (score 1):

•   To remediate a risky user-based policy, ensure the ‘Remediation’ technical profile is called after the ‘Evaluation’ technical profile is executed. If ‘Evaluation’ is invoked without ‘Remediation’, the risk state will be ‘At Risk’. When the ‘Evaluation’ technical profile recommendation returns ‘Block’, the call to the ‘Evaluation’ technical profile is not required. The risk state is set to ‘At Risk’. The following example shows a Conditional Access technical profile used to remediate the identified threat: -

Conditional Access Evaluation risk technical profile -

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="ConditionalAccessEvaluation">
 <DisplayName>Conditional Access Provider</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" 
    Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ConditionalAccessProtocolProvider, 
    Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
   <Metadata>
    <Item Key="OperationType">Evaluation</Item>
    </Metadata>
      ...
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Conditional Access Remediation risk technical profile -

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ConditionalAccessRemediation">
    <DisplayName>Conditional Access Remediation</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" 
    Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ConditionalAccessProtocolProvider, 
     Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    <Metadata>
  <Item Key="OperationType">Remediation</Item>
  </Metadata>
   ...
  </TechnicalProfile>
```

•   You will still get the user flow sign-ins as incidents in the risky users report after the above technical profiles are executed as default security provisions are disabled before configuring the Azure AD B2C conditional access policy, but they will be considered remediated after you configure the technical profile and configure the user risk conditional access policy. Thus, you can upload and configure the above technical profiles in identity experience framework section of Azure AD B2C and associate them with the required application.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/conditional-access-user-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#template-2-user-risk-based-conditional-access

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/howto-identity-protection-configure-risk-policies

Comment: I've already done in this way, for me it's not working. The thing is I set the user risk conditional access policy with grant access "Require multi-factor authentication". And my B2C user flow uses Conditional Access technical profile used to remediate the identified threat with "mfa" as ChallengesSatisfied value and no remediation happens. But if I change the risk conditional access rule to "Require password change" and makes user to change the password during user flow, then remediation happens for the risky user with explanation "User performed secured password change"

Comment: You can run a powershell script named 'Invoke-AzureADIPDismissRiskyUser.ps1' which is included in the github repo that is provided in here : - https://github.com/AzureAD/IdentityProtectionTools. By running this script through powershell, you can dismiss all the user sign in risks detected.

Comment: This is not the way for me, I want to allow users to self-remediate by going through the MFA step in my user flow

Comment: Then I think, this link might explain better the self remediation of the risks detected during user flow in MFA: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/howto-identity-protection-remediate-unblock#self-remediation-with-risk-policy